# How would I solve this fraction division problem?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$$\frac {\frac {5}{8}} {2\frac{1}{2}}$$

I understand how to divide it by flipping the numbers (reciprocal) and what not. I just don't know what to do with the $2$ next to the division sign.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it means $2\frac{1}{2}$ which is $\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't even notice that it was a mixed fraction. Thought it might have been something else. Thanks!

Comment: Yet another reason to either parenthesize or just use improper fractions...

Answer (score 0):

We have:$$\frac {\frac {5}{8}} {2\frac{1}{2}}$$
We will need to **convert the mixed number (a combination of a whole number and a fraction) to an improper fraction**:

$\implies $  $$\frac{\frac {5}{8}}{\frac{5}{2}}$$
We'll need to rotate $\frac{5}{2}$.

$\implies $ $\frac{5}{8} * \frac {2}{5} = \frac {1} {4}$